# How to export layers to pages of a pdf file in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, pdf, cs5, photoshop-scripting

I need to save each layer of my psd document as a page in a multi-page PDF file (or as a single-page PDF file each as I can combine them later). File->save as->PDF works for 1 layer at a time, but I don't fancy doing this for all 150 pages of the document.

I also tried the File->Scripts->Export layers to files, but it runs incredibly slowly (actually slower than me doing it manually) and I also have to output them to images, then re-import them in acrobat which doesn't allow me (or I haven't found the option anyway) to save the document in the PDF/X-1a:2001 format I require (which is an option from the photoshop file->save as dialog).

Is there a better way? Even recommendations for another program are welcome, but obviously I would prefer Photoshop solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use `File->Scripts->Export layers to files` to create PDFs.  Choose `PDF` under `File type` in the `Export Layers to Files` dialog box.  It's easy to miss since it's the option just above `PSD`.

As far as being slow... Don't know how big your image is or how many layers there are, but on an old (2008) MacBook Pro it exported a 2848x4288 pixel image's four layers in less than 30 seconds.  I can't speak to your configuration.  But at least it can run without having to convert the results from images to PDFs.

Comment: I believe at the beginning of the OP's second paragraph he states: "I also tried the File->Scripts->Export layers to files, but it runs incredibly slowly" so including it in your answer would technically not be an answer to his question, no?

Comment: It's kind of in the grey area I think. The OP hadn't found that you can export layers directly to PDF which eliminates having to convert from image files to PDF. I thought that that might speed up the workflow enough to make Export to Layers a viable solution to the OP

Answer (score 2):

I try to wrap my head around the thought processes where someone builds 150 Photoshop files that are destined for print production. If it's a book, manual, catalog, or something similar you sort of created way more work for yourself by not using proper tools from the start. But then again, maybe there's some reason, I'm not considering, in which you *had* to use Photoshop for every page.

But in any event, use **Adobe Indesign**. Place all the Photoshop pages into an Indesign document. Note, for press you'll need 148 or 152 pages - 150 pages will *not* work for printing (assuming it's a book or similar).

Then simply export your Indesign file for PDF/X-1a.

Comment: I must have missed the bit where they stated they needed the PDF for print production?

Comment: I also needed to find a solution to this and the InDesign option worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy with CS1-3 or CS6+:

1. Install and run Trevor Morris' [Layers to Comps](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/layers-comps.html) script.
2. Run the built-in "Layer Comps to PDF..." script.
3. That's it.

If you're running CS4 or 5, the "Layer Comps to PDF..." script is [not available](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/we_want_back_the_pdf_presentation). In that case, Eric's [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38836/33239) is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Hi Chad, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

I use PSD for most of my work. It doesn't make sense to pay for Indesign for the few moments I use it.

Best way to do this is export the layers to file as said above. File->Scripts->Export layers to files

What you want to do next is take all those files and merge them into one PDF. Photoshop allows you to do this easily **File->Automate->PDF Presentation**

Comment: This answer is better than the highest voted option because it preserves print quality type and similar objects without rasterizing them. You also get a multipage PDF as opposed to multiple files.

Comment: This is the best answer, generates one PDF in two simple steps!

Answer (score 0):

In photoshop 2020 File > Export > Layers to files
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@0xFK - yes, in newer Creative Cloud programs, I agree that Export > Layers to Files from Photoshop is a great option. That command will provide you with many image files. If you have Adobe Acrobat, moving out of Photoshop at this point is ideal. In that case, you could quickly create a pdf combining those many image files using Adobe Acrobat's File > Combine Files into a Single PDF command.[image]