# How to export groups to separate PDF files in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, export, photoshop-scripting

I have 180 groups (see image for example), each group is a different label design. I need to export each group as an individual PDF file.

[image: Group = Label Design]

What is the best way to achieve this? I know how to export them individually and how to bulk export to png, jpg etc. but I can't figure out how to export to PDF. I've tried exporting layer comps but that exports as one big pdf and not individual files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT - I'm not looking to batch export Photoshop layers to individual PNG files.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I don't think this is a duplicate question. I'm looking to export to PDF and not PNG. I already know how to batch export to PNG and this requires a different method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export layers to pages of a pdf file in Photoshop CS5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38834/how-to-export-layers-to-pages-of-a-pdf-file-in-photoshop-cs5)

Comment: Almost any of those answers in my last comment should work for you.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor That's great, thank you. Not sure how I missed this

Comment: "export layers as pdf photoshop" is the first hit on Google

Comment: @BLS93: If you think that the answers to another question solved your problem, please mark it as a duplicate yourself (*flag → should be closed → duplicate*).

Comment: [**THIS**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/126405/3270) will also work if you create a layer comp for each group.. then you can `Export Layer Comps to PDF`

Answer (score 0):

Right click each group and 'Merge Group', do this individually for each group. Select all files and then Export Layers To Files and select PDF. This is the easiest way I've found so far. I was actually looking for a script or method to do the individual grouping automatically but haven't found a method yet.