# How to Export Layers to File but take into account the Adjustment Layer's Tweaks?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have document with 5 layers, each of those layers are are full of different colors. I want to essentially export the Desaturated versions of each layer. I got past my first hurdle (which was how do I apply an affect on all layers at once by creating an adjustment layer). But now when I tried exporting those layers to files, the adjustment layer's affect was not added.

I've read similar answers where you'd have to either create a custom script file or or an action scriplet that would apply this change to files in a folder. But I'm really surprised that there's no standard option that would say something like:

Export Layers to file:
 - Apply Adjustment layer during export?

Does this exist under a different set of rules or will there still be a manual process involved like I've read in other threads?

Answer (score 3):

Save each set up as a **Layer Comp**. Then Save **Layer Comps to files**.

[image]

To create a **Layer Comp**, merely toggle visibility of layer(s) on or off, then create a New Layer Comp via the "new" button at the bottom of the Layer Comp Panel (Window > Layer Comps).

Do this for each change in visibility you want to save as a file.

So... you can create a layer comp of...

- `Layer 1 and the adjustment layer`
- `Layer 3 and the adjustment layer`
- `Layer 5 and a different adjustment layer`

[image]

The end result of the export will be 3 files from 3 layer comps all with the same visibility you see when *those* layers are visible in the Layers Panel.

[image]

Layer Comps are composite images based upon *visibility* of the *exiting* layers. They will export as "sets" containing all visible layers (adjustment or otherwise) rather than individual layers with an adjustment.

Layer Comps can also be used to "quick toggle" visibility **sets** in the Photoshop file. With only one click on a saved Layer Comp and you can change the visibility of many layers.